# 2 level nested routing in react-router doesn't route properly the first level

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am trying to make 2 level routing using react-router-dom.

**Goal:** Firstly we choose one of few divisions (e.g. F1/F2), then we can choose something from the menu (news, announcement, etc. **specific for that division**). We should be able to switch divisions at any time.

**Current state:** It works only if we choose a division first, then something from the menu. When we want to switch division (after playing with the menu) path is breaking in form of *"/F2-2020/F2-2020"*

Old Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-silence-26isr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**EDIT:**
I would like to reorganise the code so App.js has following structure:

```
<Divisions /> <- here we choose first level of routing, eg. /F1-2020
<Menu /> <- here we choose second level of routing, eg. /F1-2020/news or eg. /GT3-ACC/news
<Content /> (Displays content based on the route)
```

As previously, the Goal is to choose one of few divisions (e.g. F1/F2), then we can choose something from the menu (news, announcement, etc. specific for that division). We should be able to switch divisions at any time.

Unfortunately, since I am not invoking the Content component as the switch, I cannot get match.url and match.path from the higher-level routing. Here's the code where I cannot apply routing:
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-pascal-l2jmr?file=/src/components/Content.js

I tried to overcome the issue with getting the chosen division as a variable and passing it to the Content component, but the solutions seem to strange and may be prone to errors:
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-cdn-o4xfu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

The division paths are missing a `/`.

```js
[
  {
    path: '/F1-2020',
  },
  {
    path: '/F2-2020',
  },
  {
    path: '/GT3-ACC',
  },
]
```

You can omit `/` when displaying the division name.

```
<div>
  {division.path.slice(1)}
</div>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-wave-gr5fq?file=/src/components/Divisions.js)

Comment: You are brilliant! This works! I would never find an answer to this... I am very grateful for your help Dear Arun :)

Comment: @Piaer No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: Dear @Arun, unfortunately I would like to reorganise the code but I am not able to force the router to work. Maybe I am trying something impossible? I would be glad for hints... New explanation is in the "EDIT" of the main thread.

Comment: @Piaer I would create two different routes `/:divisionId` and `/:divisionId/:pageId`  rendering `Division` and `DivisionPage` (Page referring to news, announcements, etc.) components respectively. Take a look at this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-microservice-wkggx?file=/src/App.js) for an example.

Comment: This is beautiful <3 Thank you very much Arun. Now I will easily refactor the code to suit my needs. This is probably very simple but I can't understand routing... I am very thankful for your time to fix the code.
EDIT: Also thanks for an idea of moving data to separate folder. I would create whole code around it, so code will be more universal :)